# How to open a modal via effect and close it after a specific action was dispatched

Tags: angular, ngrx-effects

I wonder if there is a better approach than mine to close a dialog after a specific action was dispatched. Currently i got a CalendarEventDeleteDialog with options "yes" and "no". If the user chooses "yes" a CalendarEventDeleteAction gets dispatched followed by a CalendarEventDeletedAction.
Key issue: I want to be able to show progress spinner during the request inside the dialog and close it when the CalendarEvent**Deleted**Action gets dispatched.

Using Angular 12 with `@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap` for Modal handling.

My first approach was to dispatch the **delete** action from the dialog component itself. Then wait for the **deleted** action on the main actions$ stream and finally close the dialog. But it feels not ideal to hook into the main actions$ stream there:

calendar-event-delete-dialog.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'calendar-event-delete-dialog',
  templateUrl: './calendar-event-delete-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./calendar-event-delete-dialog.component.scss']
})
export class CalendarEventDeleteDialogComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() event: CalendarEvent;

  constructor(
    public dialog: NgbActiveModal,
    private actions$: Actions,
    private calendarEventStore: CalendarEventStore
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  deleteEvent(): void {
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(calendarEventActionMap.deleted),
      take(1), // just take one and unsubscribe
    ).subscribe(() => {
      this.dialog.close();
    });

    this.calendarEventStore.delete(this.event.id); // Dispatch delete action
  }
}
```

calendar-event-delete-dialog.component.html

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Termin löschen bestätigen</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="dialog.close()">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    Wollen Sie den Termin <strong>{{ event.title }}</strong> wirklich löschen?
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <div class="d-flex">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteEvent()">
            Ja
        </button>
        <button class="btn" (click)="dialog.dismiss()">
            Abbruch
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I aim for a more fluent solution only on effects layer. All within one action stream
Something like:

```
openCalendarEventDeleteDialog$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(deleteCalendarEventWithConfirm),
      exhaustMap(action => {
        const dialog = this.dialog.open(CalendarEventDeleteDialogComponent);
        (dialog.componentInstance as CalendarEventDeleteDialogComponent).event = action.event;
        return // wait for deleted action;
      })
      // close dialog

  ));
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try creating another effect.

```
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
...
openCalendarEventDeleteDialog$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(deleteCalendarEventWithConfirm),
      exhaustMap(action => {
        const dialog = this.dialog.open(CalendarEventDeleteDialogComponent);
        (dialog.componentInstance as CalendarEventDeleteDialogComponent).event = action.event;
         // get rid of return now with { dispatch: false }
        // return // wait for deleted action;
      })
      // close dialog
  // add dispatch: false here if you're not dispatching an action
  // after deleteCalendarEventWithConfirm action.
  ), { dispatch: false });

closeCalendarEventDeleteDialog$ = createEffect(() => this.actions.pipe(
  ofType(calendarEventActionMap.deleted),
  tap(action => {
    // close the dialog
  });
), { dispatch: false });
```

And then you can remove the `actions$` dependency and the subscription in the component.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how do i reference to exactly this modal to close it `dialog.close()` in the second effects tap function. I could save a reference to the effects class instance to access it via `this.dialog.close()` but this doesnt feel right(?). Also i could dismiss all dialogs over dialogService.dismissAll() which closes the modal but all others too.

Comment: That's a question I had for you as well but I did not ask, in essence how do you have a handle on the `dialog` in the effect as well? What I would do if I were you is that in the `calendarEventActionMap.deleted` action, have the payload be the `dialog` that should be closed, send this reference of the dialog every time this action is dispatched and then in the `tap` you can have a handle on it with the `action` argument. Makes sense?

Comment: Hey Ali, maybe thats the way to go for now. Thanks for your help.